# Does the catch in try-with-resources cover the code in parentheses?

Tags: java, try-with-resources

It is unclear from the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) if a `catch` following a `try-with-resources` covers the initialization part or not.

In other words, given this code fragment:

```
    try (InputStream in = getSomeStream()) {
        System.out.println(in.read());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("IOException: " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

Would my `catch` be invoked if an `IOException` is thrown **inside `getSomeStream()`?**

Or does the `catch` only cover the block inside curly braces, i.e.  `System.out.println(in.read())`?

Comment: Taken from: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

"A try-with-resources statement can have catch and finally blocks just like an ordinary try statement. In a try-with-resources statement, any catch or finally block is run after the resources declared have been closed."

This means that your catch-block will get processed as usual. You only have not to care for the resource to be closed afterwards as this happens before catch is reached.

Comment: @DiabolicWords Am I missing something? Is there anything in that paragraph which answers the question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3), your example is an extended try-with-resources.

> A try-with-resources statement with at least one catch clause and/or a
>   finally clause is called an extended try-with-resources statement.

In that case :

> The effect of the translation is to put the resource specification
>   "inside" the try statement. **This allows a catch clause** of an extended
>   try-with-resources statement **to catch an exception due to the**
>   **automatic initialization** or closing of any resource.

So yes, the exception will be caught by your `catch` block.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is covered. Running

```
try (InputStream in = getSomeStream()) {
  System.out.println(in.read());
} catch (IOException e) {
  System.err.println("IOException: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

with

```
static InputStream getSomeStream() throws IOException {
  throw new IOException();
}
```

prints

> IOException: null

So yes, the Exception thrown in the initialization part is caught in the catch block.

Answer (score 0):

The Oracle tutorials are authoritative but not normative. The JLS
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3.2
answers your question completely: Yes.

Read the Fine Manual.